# Data-view doesn't refresh with projection DAC

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am using Kit Assembly Graph, It used INKITRegister projection class, I have created another DAC INKITRegisterExt(a seperate database table)  it uses INKITRegister as parent, But when i click on navigation button then extension class data is not showing as per selected INKitRegister.

For example if "A" kit assembly is selected then extension table show "A" related data, but when i click on navigation then it show "A" data not another selected INKitRegister data. but when a  is selected then it blankout extension fields, but once "A" data is shown then it always shown data "A" data not another navigate kit assembly data, what am i doing wrong?

I have used below query for extension table in Extension Graph

```
    public PXSelect<INRegisterKitAssemblyExt,
                      Where<INRegisterKitAssemblyExt.refNbr,
                       Equal<Current<INKitRegister.refNbr>>, And<INRegisterKitAssemblyExt.kitRevisionID, Equal<Current<INKitRegister.kitRevisionID>>>>> RegisterAssemblyExtDtl;

protected virtual void INKitRegister_KitInventoryID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e) {
    if(RegisterAssemblyExtDtl.Current == null) {
                RegisterAssemblyExtDtl.Insert();
            }
 RegisterAssemblyExtDtl.Current.Text = "Value of A";
}
```

Comment: is INKITRegisterExt an extension DAC of INKITRegister?

Comment: Yes,  INKITRegisterExt is an extension DAC of INKITRegister. I have made a separate table not add the columns in INKITRegister. check in inventory selection i added a row in that extension table.

Comment: you dont need to define a Datamember in order to access the extended fields. They should be immediately available to be added to the page.

Comment: its not available, INKItRegister is a Projection DAC, and made extension table and DAC mention below, but it cleanup whole view in publish screen. any help?

[PXTable(typeof(INKitRegister.refNbr),
         typeof(INKitRegister.KitRevisionId))]
   
   public class INRegisterKitAssemblyExt: PXCacheExtension<INKitRegister> {
   
   // My Fields as well as refNbr and KitRevison is also here
   
   }

Comment: could you edit your question and include all code samples available? Dac extension, Graph extension, etc...

Comment: Please check the link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61642436/how-to-work-with-extension-table-with-projection-inkitassembly-projection-class

Answer (score 0):

Primary DAC of PXSelect dataview should not be on extension class:

```
PXSelect<INRegisterKitAssemblyExt, ...
```

You should use base DAC of extension instead:

```
PXSelect<INKitRegister, ..
```

INKitRegister is a projection DAC on INRegister DAC:

```
[PXPrimaryGraph(typeof(KitAssemblyEntry))]
[PXCacheName(Messages.INKit)]
[PXProjection(typeof(Select2<INRegister, InnerJoin<INTran, On<INRegister.FK.KitTran>>>), 
              Persistent=true)]
[Serializable]
public partial class INKitRegister : IBqlTable, ILSPrimary
```

You are trying to add the database bound field to the INKitRegister projection but no INKitRegister database table exists:

```
public class INRegisterKitAssemblyExt: PXCacheExtension<INKitRegister>
```

You should use a DAC extension on the actual database table INRegister used by the projection to persist the fields:

```
public class INRegisterKitAssemblyExt: PXCacheExtension<INRegister>
```